# How to resolve Duplicate Class error in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

1. I am getting Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1).
2. I have not seen an answer that clears up my issue. I appreciate any assistance.

   ```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
    apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'



    android {
        compileSdkVersion target_sdk_version
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
        android.buildFeatures.dataBinding


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion target_sdk_version
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/main.kotlin_module'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable = true
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            testCoverageEnabled false
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    productFlavors {
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    sourceSets {

        main {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'

        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility '1.8'
        targetCompatibility '1.8'
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'GradleDependency', 'GoogleAppIndexingWarning'
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'org.jetbrains.kotlin' && requested.name == 'kotlin-reflect') {
                details.useVersion kotlin_version
                 }
            }
        }
    }

    buildscript {
        ext {
           gson_version = "2.8.2"
           dagger_version = '2.25.2'
           rx_version = '2.2.15'
           glide_version = "4.7.1"
           rx_firebase_version = "1.1.3"
           support_version = '28.0.0'
           rx_android_version = '2.1.1'
           glide_version = '4.11.0'
           target_sdk_version = 29
        }
    }



    dependencies {

        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        def nav_version = "2.3.0"
        def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
        def arch_version = "2.1.0"
        def firebase_config = '19.2.0'
        implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$firebase_config",{
            // protobuf-lite that firebase-config and Tink depends on.
            exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf',module: 'protobuf-javalite'
            exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf',module: 'protobuf-lite'
        })

        //Base SDK
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.16.13'

        //Dagger
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.28.1'
        kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.1'
        kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.28.1'
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.28.1'

        //Firebase/Amazon
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-iot:2.16.13'
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.16.13'
        implementation "com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.6"
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:5.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'

        ///Glide
        implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
        kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"

        //JETBRAINS
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72'

        //Kotlin
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72'
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.7'
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7'
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.11.1'

        //Lifecycle
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/android.arch.lifecycle/common-java8
        implementation(group: 'androidx.lifecycle', name: 'lifecycle-common-java8', version: '2.2.0')

        // Annotation processor
        // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0-alpha05'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0-alpha05'
        implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.3.0"
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'

        // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
        // optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"
        // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
        testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version"

        kapt 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:4.0.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.0'

        //Mini
        implementation 'com.github.pabloogc:Mini:1.0.5'
        kapt 'com.github.pabloogc.Mini:mini-processor:1.0.5'
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.pabloogc.Mini:mini-processor:1.0.5'

        // Required for Cognito
        implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoauth:2.16.13@aar') { transitive = true }

        //Rx
        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19'
        implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rx_android_version"
        implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.5@aar'

        //Support
        implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha06'
        implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
        implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta8'

        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.5.0-alpha01'
        implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-alpha06'
        implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-alpha06'
        implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'

        implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
        implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'

        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'

        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
        implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'


        implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
        implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.1'
        implementation 'com.pavelsikun:material-seekbar-preference:2.3.0'
        implementation 'info.guardianproject.panic:panic:1.0'
        implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.6.1'
        implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5'
        implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'

        //Test
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
        testImplementation 'com.natpryce:hamkrest:1.7.0.0'
        testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
        testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.6.2'
        androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-rc01'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-rc01'

    }
    repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/spek" }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    //kotlin annotation processor
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

    apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

    }

    kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
        }
    }
    ...
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an exclusion on one of the imports so it only adds the package once.

Example:

```
// Now junit will not include hamcrest library. Therefore there will be no 
//dependency conflict. 
 compile ('junit:junit:4.12'){
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module:'hamcrest-core'
}
```

Comment: implementation ('junit:junit:4.12'){
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module:'hamcrest-core'
    } /* This worked! Thank you*/

Comment: @EugeneHoyt perfect! You need to mark this as the answer - will help other people too